# C# Thread Termination and Thread.Abort()

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

In MSDN, the description of the Thread.Abort() method says: "Calling this method **usually** terminates the thread."

Why not ALWAYS?

In which cases it doesn't terminate the thread?

Are there any other possibility to terminate threads?

Answer (score 63):

`Thread.Abort()` injects a `ThreadAbortException` on the thread. The thread may cancel the request by calling `Thread.ResetAbort()`. Also, there are certain code parts, such as `finally` block that will execute before the exception is handled. If for some reason the thread is stuck in such a block the exception will never be raised on the thread.

As the caller has very little control over the state of the thread when calling `Abort()`, it is generally not advisable to do so. Pass a message to the thread requesting termination instead.

Comment: What kind of a message? Do you mean a method invokation?

Comment: That depends on how you pass data between your threads. E.g. if your thread is a worker thread with a task queue, you can queue a PleaseTerminate message and let the thread handle it gracefully.

Comment: My thread has one big problem that mast be solved, were is no task queue.

Comment: As I said, it depends on how your thread code is designed. Perhaps you could signal through a member variable then. It is hard to be more specific without the actual code available.

Answer (score 56):

> In which cases it doesn't terminate the thread?

This question is a duplicate.

[What's wrong with using Thread.Abort()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1559255/whats-wrong-with-using-thread-abort/1560567#1560567)

> Are there any other posibility to terminate threads?

Yes. Your problem is that you should never start up a thread that you cannot tell politely to stop, and it stops in a timely manner. If you are in a situation where you have to start up a thread that might be (1) hard to stop, (2) buggy, or worst of all (3) hostile to the user, then the right thing to do is to make a new process, start the thread in the new process, and then *terminate the process* when you want the thread to go down. The only thing that can guarantee safe termination of an uncooperative thread is the operating system taking down its entire process.

See my excessively long answer to this question for more details:

[Using lock statement within a loop in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2113261/using-lock-statement-within-a-loop-in-c)

The relevant bit is the bit at the end where I discuss what the considerations are regarding how long you should wait for a thread to kill itself before you abort it.

Comment: Eric, how should I politely tell a thread to stop if that thread is waiting on a synchronization object, e.g. EventWaitHandle.WaitOne();?

Comment: @Corvin: the contract between two threads that describes how one thread is to communicate with another is up to the authors of the code that runs on those threads. If you have requirements that (1) a thread X must wait on an object potentially forever, and (2) that thread Y must be able to cleanly shut down thread X in a finite amount of time then I think you have contradictory requirements; decide which one wins. If the former, then thread Y is going to have to wait. If the latter, then thread X shouldn't be waiting forever, it should wait some small amount of time.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Consider the following architecture: I have an application that has to minimize itself when a certain system-wide event happens. I have a thread in that application that waits on a global named event and does its work when that event is set. On the other side, my application may have to quit before the event happens, having to close that waiting thread. What is the samurai way to code such a thing?

Comment: @Corvin: You could have a loop that waits (with a short timeout) for the event, then checks if it should stop trying to wait (so it can exit normally). This way, you can signal your thread that it should stop, and you should only have to wait as long as your timeout for it to stop.

Comment: @Corvin, if you make that waiting thread a background thread, then you shouldn't have to close it before the application quits.

Answer (score 18):

> Why not ALWAYS?
>   In which cases it doesn't termenate the thread?

For starters, a thread may catch a [**`ThreadAbortException`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadabortexception.aspx) and cancel its own termination. Or it could perform a computation that takes forever while you're trying to abort it. Because of this, the runtime can't guarantee that the thread will always terminate after you ask it to.

**[`ThreadAbortException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadabortexception.aspx)** has more:

> When a call is made to the Abort  method to destroy a thread, the common language runtime throws a ThreadAbortException. ThreadAbortException is a special exception that can be caught, but it will automatically be raised again at the end of the catch block. When this exception is raised, the runtime executes all the finally blocks before ending the thread. **Since the thread can do an unbounded computation in the finally blocks, or call `Thread.ResetAbort()` to cancel the abort, there is no guarantee that the thread will ever end.**

You don't need to `Abort()` a thread manually. The CLR will do all of the dirty work for you if you simply let the method in the thread return; that will end the thread normally.

Comment: I do need to Abort() it, because of a message loop started on that thread (Dispatcher.Run();). 

If I understand it correct, I need to Invoke a method calling return into the thread to finish it?

Answer (score 7):

`FileStream.Read()` to a named pipe that is currently not receiving anything (read call blocks while waiting for incoming data) will not respond to `Thread.Abort()`. It remains inside the `Read()` call.

Answer (score 6):

What if a thread is holding a lock and is aborted / killed  ? Resources remain stuck

> It works fine when when a thread calls
> abort itself but not by other thread.
> Abort, forcefully terminates the
> affected thread even if it has not
> completed its task and provides no
> opportunity for the cleanup of
> resources

reference [**MSDN**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1327102/how-to-kill-a-thread-instantly-in-c)

---

see:  [**Managed Threading Best Practices**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1c9txz50.aspx)

Answer (score 6):

I can't seem to abort a thread that is stuck in a loop:

```
//immortal
Thread th1 = new Thread(() => { while (true) {}});
```

I can however abort the thread if sleeps during the loop:

```
//mortal
Thread th2 = new Thread(() => { while (true) { Thread.Sleep(1000); }});
```

Comment: this doesn't appear to be true, I ran a test program:`{var th = new Thread(() =>
            {     int i = 0;

                try
                {
                    while (true)
                    {
                        i++;
                    }
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("aborting@ {0}", i);
                }
            });
            th.Start();
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            th.Abort();
            th.Join();
        }

Answer (score 4):

ThreadAborts will not occur inside a finally block or between [BeginCriticalRegion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.begincriticalregion.aspx) and [EndCriticalRegion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.endcriticalregion.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

Because you can catch the `ThreadAbortException` and call `Thread.ResetAbort` inside the handler.

Answer (score 0):

OT: For a comprehensive, language-agnostic, questionably useful and darned funny take on concurrency, see [Verity Stob](http://www.theregister.co.uk/2009/12/10/verity_stob/)!

Answer (score 0):

As *john feminella* stated from MSDN

> When this exception is raised, the runtime executes all the finally
> blocks before ending the thread.

For example this Abort never ends:

```
var thread = new Thread(action) { IsBackground = true };
thread.Start();
Thread.Sleep(2000);
thread.Abort();

while (!thread.Join(1000))
{
    Console.WriteLine(thread.ThreadState);
}

void action()
{
    try
    {
        while (true) { }
    }
    catch { }
    finally
    {
        while (true) { }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I've had cases where the thread has been too busy to hear the Abort() call, which usually results in a ThreadAbortingException being thrown to my code.