# How to terminate a thread with the OnStop Method (C#)

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I have a a thread I am trying to stop in the OnStop method, could someone demonstrate how you could terminate / stop a thread with it:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// OnStop: Put your stop code here
    /// - Stop threads, set final data, etc.
    /// </summary>
    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        base.OnStop();
    }
```

Taking into account, that is start like follows:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// OnStart: Put startup code here
    ///  - Start threads, get inital data, etc.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="args"></param>
    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        Thread MyThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(MyThreadStarter));
        MyThread.Start();

        base.OnStart(args);
    }

    private void MyThreadStarter()
    {
        realtime obj = new realtime();
        obj.Starter();
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this example from MS [How to: Create and Terminate Threads (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7a2f3ay4%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

```
objThread.Abort();
```

use this in `OnStop()` method...

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2251964/c-thread-termination-and-thread-abort, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1559255/whats-wrong-with-using-thread-abort/1560567#1560567, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty8d3wta.aspx on the dangers of using Thread.Abort() and why you should avoid it.