# How do I terminate a C# thread using IDisposables

Tags: c#, multithreading, garbage-collection, idisposable

This is a C# .NET Console application.
My parent class will instantiate a child class with:

```
Thread oThread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(oAlpha.init));
oThread.Start(this)
```

oThread will use iDisposable elements.

Under certain conditions (like when I have updated infomration I want oThread to process instead of old/stale information), I'd like the parent to terminate oThread (the child) at any time and restart it.   Should I be calling an event handler in the child to Dispose()?

Is there a clean way to do this without having memory leaks?

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Thanks
-Ed

Comment: There are very good comments about `Thread.Abort` you probably should check out - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2251964/c-sharp-thread-termination-and-thread-abort