# Kill multi threading Server's thread c#

Tags: c#, multithreading, function, server

I have a program that starts a server thread, in that thread I wait for user connections, but  sometimes (if the user presses "E") I want to close that server thread but it's not working. I tried

```
'thread'.abort() - but it's freezing and not stopping the thread
```

here it the server code:

```
 private void start()
    {
        try
        {
            this.serverSocket = new TcpListener(8888);                      // creating the Server TCP socket 
            this.clientSocket = default(TcpClient);                         // creating the User socket variable  

            // starting the server
            this.serverSocket.Start();

            Console.WriteLine("->> server started");                        // printing to log 

            // for always 
            while (true)
            {
                counter += 1;                                               // new user 
                this.clientSocket = this.serverSocket.AcceptTcpClient();    // accepting user 
                Console.WriteLine(" ->> User connected");                   // printing to log 
                // User creatinon
                ConnectedUser user = new ConnectedUser(this.clientSocket);
                user.startListerner();
            }

            this.clientSocket.Close();
            this.serverSocket.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine(" >> " + "exit");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        catch
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error launching the Server");
        }

    }
```

and I run it this way:

```
this.server = new Thread(start);
server.Start();
```

I want to terminate it , how can I do that ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2251964/c-sharp-thread-termination-and-thread-abort

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to use a [`CancellationTokenSource`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.cancellationtokensource(v=vs.110).aspx) to signal your thread to terminate itself. Using `Thread.Abort` is not recommended because it terminates the thread without letting it properly clean up first.

To use the cancellation token, you create an instance of `CancellationTokenSource` and then pass the token to your thread function (or to an object that wraps the new thread state. Inside the thread function you can then check the `IsCancellationRequested` property of the token periodically to see if the thread should shut down. You can pass the same cancellation token to I/O functions so they attempt to cancel a blocking operation.

Read [this question/ answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2251964/c-sharp-thread-termination-and-thread-abort) for more detail about the possible issues caused by `Thread.Abort`. Specifically read Eric Lippert's response to that question where he mentions never to start a thread that you cannot politely stop.