# How to combine asynchrony with locking?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asynchronous

As the famous [blog post from Stephen Cleary](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html) dictates, one should never try to run async code synchronously (e.g. via `Task.RunSynchronously()` or accessing `Task.Result`). On the other hand, you can't use async/await inside `lock` statement.

My use case is ASP.NET Core app, which uses `IMemoryCache` to cache some data. Now when the data is not available, (e.g. cache is dropped) I have to repopulate it, and that should be guarded with `lock`.

```
public TItem Get<TItem>(object key, Func<TItem> factory)
{
    if (!_memoryCache.TryGetValue(key, out TItem value))
    {
        lock (_locker)
        {
            if (!_memoryCache.TryGetValue(key, out value))
            {
                value = factory();
                Set(key, value);
            }
        }
    }
    return value;
}
```

In this example, the factory function can not be async! What should be done if it has to be async?

Comment: https://blog.cdemi.io/async-waiting-inside-c-sharp-locks/

Comment: [`SemaphoreSlim.WaitAsync`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh462805(v=vs.110).aspx) is your friend.

Comment: Looking at your question from higher perspective, I think you may be overlooking possibility of not having to lock at all, and take advantage of `Task`s themselves to do synchronization for you.  I was typing up the answer in that direction when the question got closed :(

Comment: This question deserves discussion. Just that there is a similar question with an answer, does not really mean that the problem is definitely resolved and solution is clear. Please reopen the question.

Comment: Did you read the link in the first comment? Seems to answer your questions.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

An easy way to coordinate asynchronous access to a shared variable is to use a [`SemaphoreSlim`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.semaphoreslim.waitasync). You call `WaitAsync` to begin an asynchronous lock, and `Release` to end it.

E.g.

```
private static readonly SemaphoreSlim _cachedCustomersAsyncLock = new SemaphoreSlim(1, 1);
private static ICollection<Customer> _cachedCustomers;

private async Task<ICollection<Customer>> GetCustomers()
{
    if (_cachedCustomers is null)
    {
        await _cachedCustomersAsyncLock.WaitAsync();

        try
        {
            if (_cachedCustomers is null)
            {
                _cachedCustomers = GetCustomersFromDatabase();
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            _cachedCustomersAsyncLock.Release();
        }
    }

    return _cachedCustomers;
}
```

Comment: _cachedCustomersAsyncLock is null == false you mean

Comment: @cubesnyc Actually I mean `if (_cachedCustomers is null)`. I'm using the [double-checked locking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-checked_locking) pattern and the purpose is to avoid the expensive lock operation which is only going to be needed once (when the `GetCustomers` is first accessed)

Comment: There is a bug in your code. If the `_cachedCustomers` is `null` before the `await`, and not `null` after the `await`, the semaphore will be acquired and not released.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias Good catch! Thanks. I've updated the answer

Comment: Now it's OK. :-) Btw the double-checked locking pattern is [tricky](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1964731/the-need-for-volatile-modifier-in-double-checked-locking-in-net). You risk receiving partially initialized objects if you don't use `volatile`, or `Volatile.Read`, or `Thread.MemoryBarrier`.