# Two Tasks run on the same thread which invalidates lock

Tags: c#, asynchronous, locking, task

## Edit

I find [Building Async Coordination Primitives, Part 1: AsyncManualResetEvent](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/new-task-apis-in-net-4-6/) might be related to my topic.

> In the case of TaskCompletionSource, that means that synchronous continuations can happen as part of a call to {Try}Set*, which means in our AsyncManualResetEvent example, those continuations could execute as part of the Set method.  Depending on your needs (and whether callers of Set may be ok with a potentially longer-running Set call as all synchronous continuations execute), this may or may not be what you want.

Many thanks to all of the answers, thank you for your knowledge and patience!

---

## Original Question

I know that `Task.Run` runs on a threadpool thread and threads can have re-entrancy. But **I never knew** that 2 tasks can run on the same thread when they are both **alive**!

**My Question is: is that reasonable by design? Does that mean `lock` inside an async method is meaningless (or say, `lock` cannot be trusted in async method block, if I'd like a method that doesn't allow reentrancy)?**

Code:

```
namespace TaskHijacking
{
    class Program
    {
        static TaskCompletionSource<bool> tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
        static object methodLock = new object();

        static void MethodNotAllowReetrance(string callerName)
        {
            lock(methodLock)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Enter MethodNotAllowReetrance, caller: {callerName}, on thread: {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}");
                if (callerName == "task1")
                {
                    tcs.SetException(new Exception("Terminate tcs"));
                }
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
                Console.WriteLine($"Exit MethodNotAllowReetrance, caller: {callerName}, on thread: {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}");
            }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var task1 = Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                await Task.Delay(1000);
                MethodNotAllowReetrance("task1");
            });

            var task2 = Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                try
                {
                    await tcs.Task;  // await here until task SetException on tcs
                }
                catch
                {
                    // Omit the exception
                }
                MethodNotAllowReetrance("task2");
            });

            Task.WaitAll(task1, task2);

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Enter MethodNotAllowReetrance, caller: task1, on thread: 6
Enter MethodNotAllowReetrance, caller: task2, on thread: 6
Exit MethodNotAllowReetrance, caller: task2, on thread: 6
Exit MethodNotAllowReetrance, caller: task1, on thread: 6
```

The control flow of the thread 6 is shown in the figure:

[image]

Comment: *"I know that Tasks run on threads"* -- Nope, in general tasks [are not running on threads](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html). If you want a `Task` that runs on a single thread from start to finish, it must be a [delegate-based task](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2015/03/a-tour-of-task-part-9-delegate-tasks.html), not a promise-style task created from an `async` method.

Comment: Related: [C# Lock and Async Method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20084695/c-sharp-lock-and-async-method) and [How to combine asynchrony with locking?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44269412/how-to-combine-asynchrony-with-locking)

Comment: @TheodorZoulias Thanks, you are be right, I should've said: Tasks.Run *might* run on a threadpool thread. BTW, I also read Stephen's blogs from time to time. But focusing on my question, I just want to make sure that: should `lock` **not** be trusted in an async method, because the thread of the current task might be hijacked by another task?

Comment: @Tomingsun Well, `Task.Run` *does* run on a ThreadPool thread ([the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.run) says so), but you have no control over *which* thread.

Comment: Tomingsun the whole point of asynchronous programming is to make efficient use of threads by not blocking them. And the whole point of having a `ThreadPool` is to reuse threads, instead of starting a new thread for every tiny operation that needs a thread. Combine these two concepts together and, yes, you'll see a lot of "hijacking" going on.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias Thanks, I get your point and I totally agree. Although I must argue that the *thread hijacking* happening in my code doesn't make sense at all, since it literally **blocks** my *monitor task* by transfer the thread to *work task*.

Comment: Tomingsun multithreading is difficult. And indeed the reentrancy of the `lock` statement is one of the traps you must be constantly aware of, in order to write multithreaded code that behaves correctly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You already have several solutions. I just want to describe the *problem* a bit more. There are several factors at play here that combine to cause the observed re-entrancy.

First, `lock` is re-entrant. `lock` is strictly about mutual exclusion of *threads*, which is not the same as mutual exclusion of *code*. I think [re-entrant locks are a bad idea](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/04/recursive-re-entrant-locks.html) in the 99% case (as described on my blog), since developers generally want mutual exclusion of *code* and not *threads*. `SemaphoreSlim`, since it is not re-entrant, mutually excludes *code*. IMO re-entrant locks are a holdover from decades ago, when they were introduced as an OS concept, and the OS is just concerned about managing threads.

Next, [`TaskCompletionSource<T>` by default invokes task continuations synchronously](https://gist.github.com/StephenCleary/d5687f9d11947b7a8e3313c9fb2777bd).

Also, [`await` will schedule its method continuation as a synchronous task continuation](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/12/dont-block-in-asynchronous-code.html) (as described on my blog).

[Task continuations will *sometimes* run asynchronously even if scheduled synchronously](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/when-executesynchronously-doesnt-execute-synchronously/), but in this scenario they will run synchronously. The context captured by `await` is the thread pool context, and the completing thread (the one calling `TCS.TrySet*`) is a thread pool thread, and in that case the continuation will almost always run synchronously.

So, you end up with a thread that takes a lock, completes a TCS, thus executing the continuations of that task, which includes continuing another method, which is then able to take that same lock.

To repeat the existing solutions in other answers, to solve this you need to break that chain at some point:

- (OK) Use a non-reentrant lock. `SemaphoreSlim.WaitAsync` will still execute the continuations while holding the lock (not a good idea), but since `SemaphoreSlim` isn't re-entrant, the method continuation will (asynchronously) wait for the lock to be available.
- (Best) Use `TaskCompletionSource.RunContinuationsAsynchronously`, which will force task continuations onto a (different) thread pool thread. This is a better solution because your code is no longer invoking arbitrary code while holding a lock (i.e., the task continuations).

You can also break the chain by using a non-thread-pool context for the method `await`ing the TCS. E.g., if that method had to resume on a UI thread, then it could not be run synchronously from a thread pool thread.

From a broader perspective, if you're mixing locks and `TaskCompletionSource` instances, it sounds like you may be building (or may need) an asynchronous coordination primitive. I have [an open-source library that implements a bunch of them](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx), if that helps.

Answer (score 2):

A task is an abstraction over some amount of work. Usually this means that the work is split into parts, where the execution can be paused and resumed between parts. When resuming it may very well run on another thread. But the pausing/resuming may only be done at the `await` statements. Notably, while the task is 'paused', for example because it is waiting for IO, it does not consume any thread at all, it will only use a thread while it is actually running.

> My Question is: is that reasonable by design? Does that mean lock inside an async method is meaningless?

locks inside a async method is far from meaningless since it allows you to ensure a section of code is only run by one thread at a time.

In your first example there can be only one thread that has the lock at a time. While the lock is held that task cannot be paused/resumed since `await` is not legal while in a lock body. So a single thread will execute the entire lock body, and that thread cannot do anything else until it completes the lock body. So there is no risk of re-entrancy unless you invoke some code that can call back to the same method.

In your updated example the problem occurs due to `TaskCompletionSource.SetException`, this is allowed to reuse the current thread to run any continuation of the task immediately. To avoid this, and many other issues, make sure you only hold the lock while running a *limited* amount of code. Any method calls that may run arbitrary code risks causing deadlocks, reentrancy, and many other problems.

You can solve the specific problem by using a ManualResetEvent(Slim) to do the signaling between threads instead of using a TaskCompletionSource.

Comment: `and that thread cannot do anything else until it completes the lock body. So there is no risk of re-entrancy`, that is opposite to my updated code and illustration. In my code, the thread just leaves the lock body, and transfer to another task, into the same method, so there *is* reentrancy in my code. Could you share you thinking on that?

Comment: @Tomingsun The problem is that `SetException` can run continuations immediately. This is not fundamentally different from calling a delegate or raising an event. So do not call code that may run arbitrary code while holding a lock.

Comment: Your updated answer about *continuation* makes sense to me, upvoted for your answer.

Answer (score 2):

So your method is basically like this:

```
static void MethodNotAllowReetrance()
{
    lock (methodLock) tcs.SetResult();
}
```

...and the `tcs.Task` has a continuation attached that invokes the `MethodNotAllowReetrance`. What happens then is the same thing that would happen if your method was like this instead:

```
static void MethodNotAllowReetrance()
{
    lock (methodLock) MethodNotAllowReetrance();
}
```

The moral lesson is that you must be very careful every time you invoke any method inside a `lock`-protected region. In this particular case you have a couple of options:

1. Don't complete the `TaskCompletionSource` while holding the `lock`. Defer its completion until after you have exited the protected region:

```cs
static void MethodNotAllowReetrance()
{
    bool doComplete = false;
    lock (methodLock) doComplete = true;
    if (doComplete) tcs.SetResult();
}
```

2. Configure the `TaskCompletionSource` so that it invokes its continuations asynchronously, by passing the [`TaskCreationOptions.RunContinuationsAsynchronously`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskcreationoptions) in its constructor. This is an option that you don't have very often. For example when you cancel a [`CancellationTokenSource`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.cancellationtokensource), you don't have the option to invoke asynchronously the callbacks registered to its associated `CancellationToken`.
3. Refactor the `MethodNotAllowReetrance` method in a way that it can handle reentrancy.

Comment: I'll give option 2 a careful consideration, which seems very interesting to me, might be an alternative to lock or semaphore. Really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

Use [`SemaphoreSlim`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.semaphoreslim) instead of `lock`, since, as the documentation says:

> The SemaphoreSlim class doesn't enforce thread or task identity

In your case, it would look something like this:

```
// Semaphore only allows one request to enter at a time
private static readonly SemaphoreSlim _semaphoreSlim = new SemaphoreSlim(1, 1);

void SyncMethod() {
  _semaphoreSlim.Wait();
  try {
    // Do some sync work
  } finally {
    _semaphoreSlim.Release();
  }
}
```

The `try`/`finally` block is optional, but it makes sure that the semaphore is released even if an exception is thrown somewhere in your code.

Note that `SemaphoreSlim` also has a [`WaitAsync()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.semaphoreslim.waitasync) method, if you want to wait asynchronously to enter the semaphore.

Comment: Thanks for your nice suggestion, actually before posting this question, I've already turned to SemaphoreSlim. It is the hijack-of-thread panics me. So it is normal that thread can be hijacked from one task to another?

Comment: @Tomingsun It's normal. One task != one thread. The purpose of asynchronous tasks is that, while one task is waiting for something, the thread can be freed to work on another task instead of just sitting idle.

Comment: Gabriel if you have a reentrancy problem and try to fix it by switching from `lock` to `SemaphoreSlim(1, 1)`, most likely you'll end up with a deadlock problem. It would be like calling `_semaphoreSlim.Wait()` twice, without a `Release` between the two. The second `Wait` (or `await WaitAsync`) will never complete!

Comment: @TheodorZoulias yes, I actually use `WaitAsync` to make it work, so I suppose I should change my method name to `MethodNotAllowReentrancy` rather than `SyncMethod`, which is misleading if an async method is called *Sync* :-P. I'd like to update my solution in a new answer. But really thank you both for guiding me out of darkness.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias I guess it should be `new SemaphoreSlim(0,1)`? It's been a while since I used it and the documentation is confusing in its explanations.

Comment: It's `new SemaphoreSlim(1, 1)` if you want to use it similarly to a `lock` (acquire and then release it).