# How can I implement a thread-safe lazy-initialized singleton in C# without using the `Lazy<T>` class?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, thread-safety, singleton, lazy-initialization

I've been reading about the Singleton pattern in C# and how thread safety can be a concern, especially when it comes to lazy initialization. I'm aware of the `Lazy<T>` class which can be used to create a thread-safe lazy-initialized singleton. However, for educational purposes, I'd like to understand how one might implement this without relying on `Lazy<T>`.

Here's what I've tried so far:

```cs
public sealed class Singleton
{
    private static Singleton instance = null;
    private static readonly object padlock = new object();

    Singleton()
    {
    }

    public static Singleton Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (instance == null)
            {
                lock (padlock)
                {
                    if (instance == null)
                    {
                        instance = new Singleton();
                    }
                }
            }
            return instance;
        }
    }
}
```

1. Is the above code a proper thread-safe lazy-initialized Singleton in C#?
2. Are there potential pitfalls or performance concerns with this approach?
3. Are there alternative methods to achieve this without `Lazy<T>`?

Any insights or suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: You might find this interesting: [Double-checked locking in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394898/double-checked-locking-in-net). Or this: [The need for volatile modifier in double checked locking in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1964731/the-need-for-volatile-modifier-in-double-checked-locking-in-net).

Comment: @TheodorZoulias Thank you for answer I really like what you shared.

Comment: See also https://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Singleton

Comment: @stuartd I think that the `thread-safety` and `lazy-initialization` tags are definitely on point. Personally I wouldn't have seen this question without these tags.

Comment: Fatih Furkan you could consider closing this question as a duplicate of one of the linked questions. Although it's not an exact duplicate, the topic has been thoroughly discussed, and getting an answer here is not very likely. Alternatively you could consider posting a [self-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) if you want, with your research.

Comment: this resource offers enough answers for me https://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Singleton and other links.  I want to could  close this question as a duplicate of one of the linked questions.

Comment: There is a "Close" button under the tags of the question. Then you can select "Duplicate", and paste the URL of the duplicate question.

Comment: I didn't find "Close" button under the tags of the question.

Comment: Strange. Maybe you don't have enough reputation points. I was assuming that the author of a question can always close it as a duplicate, single-handedly. I am closing it for you.